# Old Activity views shows up again in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

An activity (Activity1) that has setup the views twice, after an activity is finished (Activity2), shows only once and then it shows again, when once again Activity2 is invoked and finished its showing the previous one of the activity. How to clear the old activity that is still lingering and affecting the views.

Answer (score 1):

Before open second activity close first activity using **finish()** function